# pass vectors to function in R

Tags: r, parameter-passing

I have a vector of POS tags.
And I want to create a global bigram vector of the POS tags.
I have created the following function in R:

```
createbi<-function(a) {
  for(i in 1:(length(a)-1)){
    bigramlist<-c(bigramlist,(paste(a[i], a[i+1], sep=" ")))
  }
}
```

here in a i want to pass a list of tags :

```
> a$POStags
 [1] "DT"  "VBZ" "DT"  "JJ"  "NN"  "VBG" "IN"  "DT"  "NNS" ","   "NNS" ","   "CC"  "NNS" "."
```

but I am not getting the bigrams in the bigramlist.I think the problem is with parameter passing.
I want output as :

```
> bigramlist
 [1] "DT VBZ" "VBZ DT" "DT JJ"  "JJ NN"  "NN VBG" "VBG IN" "IN DT"  "DT NNS" "NNS ,"  ", NNS"  "NNS ,"  ", CC"   "CC NNS"
[14] "NNS .
```

can someone help me with this I am new to R

Answer (score 2):

Here are three different approaches to your problem ordered from most to least preferable (in my opinion):

**a) paste with head/tail**

An alternative, perhaps more R-ish way to do it where `x` denotes your vector `a$POStags`, is to use `paste` directly on two subsets of `x`:

```
paste(head(x, -1), tail(x, -1))
#[1] "DT VBZ" "VBZ DT" "DT JJ"  "JJ NN"  "NN VBG" "VBG IN" "IN DT"  "DT NNS" "NNS ,"  ", NNS"  "NNS ," 
#[12] ", CC"   "CC NNS" "NNS ."
```

Of course you can put that in a function too:

```
createbi <- function(a) paste(head(a, -1), tail(a, -1))
```

**b) sapply**

Alternatively you could use an `sapply` loop as follows (but I would prefer the first approach):

```
createbi2 <- function(a) sapply(1:(length(a)-1), function(i) paste(a[i], a[i+1]))
```

**c) for loop**

If you insist on a for loop, I'd do it like this (notice preallocation of `bigramlist`):

```
createbi <- function(a) {
  n <- length(a)-1
  bigramlist <- character(n)
  for(i in 1:n){
    bigramlist[i] <- paste(a[i], a[i+1])
  }
  bigramlist
}
```

But you see by now how much simpler approach a) is than writing the for loop.